# Event order when multiple threads are waiting on synchronised on the same object

Tags: java

If I have a common thread pool that queues runnable tasks and the runnable task is the same object every time.

What happens when it reaches a block of code (within the runnable task) that has a synchronised lock? and say 5 threads are waiting on the same lock?

When it unlocks, is the synchronised block a queue line waiting to be executed and new threads join the queue, or whoever managed to grab the block first?

If there isn't a queue line, assuming I want an ordered execution, what is the best method to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

synchronized blocks do not have any defined order.  you can use a `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock` with "fair" locking to achieve the same affect as a synchronized block, but with guaranteed ordering.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the headsup. Here's more info I found for others with the same question. http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/using-reentrant-locks-for-thread-synchronization/